# "Access to undeclared static property: App\FieldCategory::$fieldCategories"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get value of static variable that is defined in  a FieldCategory model.But i'm getting error if i try to access the constant from  a crontroller.
Here is code

```
$fieldCategories = FieldCategory::find(1)->first()->constants;
$test=FieldCategory::$fieldCategories;
```

`$fieldCategories` contains a value that is the name of a constant declared in model.But its giving the following error

> "Access to undeclared static property: `App\FieldCategory::$fieldCategories`"

Comment: App\FieldCategory::fieldCategories ? So minus the dollar sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this solution I hope it will work for you.

```
$data=constant("App\FieldCategory::{$fieldCategories}");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **the value of `$fieldCategories`** as the constant name, you need to use

```
echo constant("FieldCategory::$fieldCategories");
```

With `FieldCategory::$fieldCategories` PHP will think you are trying to access a static *property*, which obviously is not a constant.

**Example:**

```
class Foo {
    const BAR = 42;
}

$prop = 'BAR';
echo constant("Foo::$prop");
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Comment: I have tried the solution but no success,giving the following error 

"Access to undeclared static property: App\FieldCategory::$FIELD_CATEGORIES"

Comment: @user1994 sorry, I misread your question. Updated for use with a constant.

Comment: Thanks for your help :),I'm attaching my answer.

Comment: @user1994 providing and accepting your own answer instead of accepting the answer that solved your problem is somewhat rude, don't you think? Also, asking a question from one account only to accept it from another account is cheating and can get you banned. Just saying.